# Boolean 'if' statement does not work

Tags: java

This code is meant to return congratulations when the two arrays are both in the same order. I have print both arrays as a test and they become the same order but the message 'congratulations'does not print. Can someone please help??

```
        boolean truefalse = Arrays.equals(original, currentarr);
        if (truefalse == true){
            System.out.println("Congratulations");
            var1 = var1 + var2; 
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrays.equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2)` compares the members of the arrays with `equals`. Therefore, for 2D arrays, when the members are arrays themselves, it compares references (since arrays don't override `Object`'s `equals`).

Use `Arrays.deepEquals` instead.